# Android application isn't closing even after using driver.close() or driver.quit() with the UiAutomator2 driver in Appium 2

Tags: automation, appium, appium-android, appium-java, uiautomatorviewer

Android application isn't closing even after using driver.close() or driver.quit() with the UiAutomator2 driver in Appium 2

```
getDesiredCapabilitiesForAndroidUsingW3C
return new UiAutomator2Options()
                .setPlatformName(ApplicationConstants.ANDROID)
                .setDeviceName(deviceName)
                .setUdid(uuid)
                .setNoReset(!isClearAppData())
                .setNewCommandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(applicationDetails.getExecutionContext() == ExecutionContext.XFI ? NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT * XFI_NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT_MULTIPLIER : NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT))
                .setAutomationName(AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2)
                .setSystemPort(SYSTEM_PORT)
                .setAppActivity(applicationDetails.getAppActivity())
                .setAppPackage(applicationDetails.getAppPackage());
```

Each test cases Application should relauch and it will use new session.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Add **fullReset** and **noReset** capabilities while creating the driver.

```html
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset",true);
capabilities.setCapability("noReset",false);
```